# Coding challenge: Solution debugging

Tags: java

A picture of code and test cases:
[image: A picture of code and test cases. Please click]

This is the problem:

Given a non-negative number "num", return true if num is within 2 of a multiple of 10. Note: (a % b) is the remainder of dividing a by b, so (7 % 5) is 2. See also: Introduction to Mod

My code fails nearTen(1) for some reason. please open the picture for details.

```
public boolean nearTen(int num) {
    if (num < 8)
        return false;

    if (num % 10 == 0)
        return true;

    while (num / 10 != 0) {
        num = num - 10;
    }

    if (num == 8 || num == 9 || num == 1 || num == 2)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The link has a picture of me running the code with test cases

Comment: 1 is less than 8.

Comment: Pay more attention to case `nearTen(1)`. What is result at *Run* column? What it should be?

Comment: how come nearTen (1) is true? is 0 a multiple of 10?

Comment: @MichelGuirguis According to your image, it outputs *false*, but it was **expected** to output *true*.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes I just noticed that. I assumed it output the reverse because I do not understand why nearTen(1) would be true.

Comment: `0` is *multiplication* of 10, specifically `0*10 = 0` and since `1` is *within 2* of 0 (which is multiple of 10) method should return `true` for `1`.

Comment: `nearTen(1)` is true because 1 is less than 8, and the first thing you do is test to see if it is less than 8 and return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean nearTen(int num) {
    if(num < 8) {
        return false;
    } else if(num % 10 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    while(num / 10 != 0) {
        num = num - 10;
    }
    if(num == 8 || num == 9 || num == 1 || num == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is your code, but in first if condition you are doing

```
if(num < 8) 
    return false
//so 100% you will fail case => input is 1
```

And your logic has some issues. Instead of using "/", we can use "%". Reason is you only consider number multiplied by 10.
for example:

- 1 / 11 / 21 / 111 / 555551 /  1000001 => last digit is 1
- 2 / 12 / 122 / 12342 /  5124512 /  1000002 => last digit is 2

for all those numbers we can ignore previous digits, and only consider last digit. Because previous digits are numbers used to multiply 10.
so this answer can be simplified to following code

```
public boolean nearTen(int num) {
    if(num < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    num %= 10;
    return num == 8 || num == 9 || (num >= 0 && num <= 2);
}
```